# Subtraction of two queries in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help to solve the issue. 
I can't create the proper working request, which could calculate the difference between two queries. 
In order to get the quantity of goods in the store, we need todeduct the amount of goods sold from the sum of all products from all suppliers.

There are two separate queries.
**1. First calculates the sum of all products from all suppliers.**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEprovider ON nb.TEreport.id_provider = nb.TEprovider.id
WHERE (LEFT(nb.TEprovider.name, 10) != 'FROM STORE') 
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102)
ORDER BY Dat DESC
```

**2. Second calculates the amount of goods sold.**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEway ON nb.TEreport.id_way = nb.TEway.id
WHERE (SUBSTRING(nb.TEway.name, 5, 8) != 'TO STORE') 
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102)
ORDER BY Dat DESC
```

**I tried to do with subqueries, but it is not what is actually needed**
For example,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) AS Dat,
  (SELECT SUM(nb.TEreport.weight)
   FROM nb.TEreport
   INNER JOIN nb.TEprovider ON nb.TEreport.id_provider = nb.TEprovider.id
   WHERE LEFT(nb.TEprovider.name, 10) != 'FROM STORE')-
  (SELECT SUM(nb.TEreport.weight)
   FROM nb.TEreport
   INNER JOIN nb.TEway ON nb.TEreport.id_way = nb.TEway.id
   WHERE SUBSTRING(nb.TEway.name, 5, 8) != 'TO STORE')
FROM nb.TEreport
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102)
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102)
ORDER BY Dat ASC
```

But in this case, the query gives no specific amount for a specific day, it just gives the sum of all numbers for the period.
How can I solve the problem?

P.S. Date is stored in seconds, that is why I used date converter .

Comment: What role this `date` is playing? Should `GoodsId` be not present here?

Comment: Do both queries return same number of rows?

Comment: Show what return the last query...

Comment: What on earth is the magic number `25568` for?

Comment: I group by date. No, it shouldn't. Yes queries return same number of rows. 25568 is 01-01-1970

Comment: ? `select DATEPART(day,25568)` returns 2 for me. It's not 01-01-1970.

Comment: @Jkterina Damien is right - 25568 is the 2nd Jan 1970. You need 25567. See for yourself on [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: You can try

```
 SELECT Dat, SUM(Goods) AS Goods
   FROM
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
        SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
   FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEprovider ON nb.TEreport.id_provider = nb.TEprovider.id
  WHERE (LEFT(nb.TEprovider.name, 10) != 'FROM STORE') 
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102)
  ORDER BY Dat DESC
  UNION ALL
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
        -SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
   FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEway ON nb.TEreport.id_way = nb.TEway.id
  WHERE (SUBSTRING(nb.TEway.name, 5, 8) != 'TO STORE') 
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.dat, 25568), 102)
  ORDER BY Dat DESC) t
GROUP BY Dat
ORDER BY Dat DESC
```

Assumption is that both your queries work fine. The idea is to invert the sign of the Goods value in second select, UNION two resultsets and then group by Dat and calculate the SUM of Goods.

You can see a simplified example in this **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28368/1)**

Comment: @Jkterina Did it help in any way?